# Stripe API call not returning object - create coupon

Tags: ajax, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a coupon on Stripe using the API - but for some reason it's not returning the object so I can get the ID back - what am I doing wrong?

**It's returning:** `{}`

Yet the coupon is created correctly on the Stripe admin panel when logged in.

Here's the server side PHP code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/core/php/include/stripe/live-env.php';

$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient($stripeSecretKey);

$stripe->coupons->create([
  'percent_off' => 20,
  'duration' => 'once',
]);

echo json_encode($stripe);
```

AJAX Code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/assets/core/php/ajax-calls/stripe/create-coupon.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log("success create coupon");
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log("error creating coupon");
        console.log(error);
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not meant to be using the return value of `$stripe->coupons->create()`?

Comment: Thanks Phil - but that doesn't work...

Comment: First you want to check your Stripe Dashboard request log to see how your request looks like, of whether you even send a request: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs

Comment: Thanks Orakaro - I didn't know that existed. The log is successful - it shows the object being returned with an ID etc within - I don't understand why I'm not getting that back in my code... Even running the page directly.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with the following code if this helps anyone in the future.

No idea why the code from the Stripe documentation isn't working though.

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/core/php/include/stripe/live-env.php';


\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripeSecretKey);

// Create a coupon
$coupon = \Stripe\Coupon::create([
    'percent_off' => 25,
    'duration' => 'once', // can be once, forever, or repeating
    'name' => '25% Off Coupon',
]);

// Retrieve the coupon ID
$couponId = $coupon->id;

echo "Coupon ID: " . $couponId;
```

Comment: "No idea why the code from the Stripe documentation isn't working though." the documentation doesn't show that you would assign the result of the call to a variable. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The coupon is the return value of calling the function on the API client.(**not** the `$stripe` value which is the API client object).

```
$coupon = $stripe->coupons->create([
  'percent_off' => 20,
  'duration' => 'once',
]);
$couponId = $coupon->id;
echo "Coupon ID: " . $couponId;
```